# Deleting duplicate values from XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to remove duplicates from a XML file using XSLT.
Input is something like this  :

```
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
    <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
```

The required output is :

```
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
```

Basically i am trying to remove duplicate records.
How do i get this done ?

Comment: Do you use XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? What happens if some items (for instance, `title` and `artist`) are the same but others differ (for instance, `price`)?

Comment: I am using XSLT 2.0 .

Comment: For now I am not considering that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all `cd` elements have the same child elements in the same order and the bar character `|` is not part of any value you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="cd" group-by="string-join(*, '|')">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Obviously if that bar character can be inside any value you could use a different character to separate the values.

Comment: can you explain this code to me or can tell some good resource from where i can read about this ?

Comment: To learn about `for-each-group`, try any XSLT 2.0 book or tutorial. The specification also has some examples that can help: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples. As for the above suggestion, the normal use of `group-by` is to group on a single item (e.g. `group-by="title"`) but as you want to make sure all child items are the same I have used `string-join(*, '|')` to concatenate all values, that allows us to group on the concatenated value. As long as the child items are the same and are in the same order this works.